# I copied just 3 lines of script from vimeo example - and it causes an 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

I copied 3 lines of code from Vimeo, and Chrome's javascript debugger says they cause an undefined error.  It tries to do a 'split' on an element that does not exist.  Here is the 3 lines of script, plus all the html, since its obviously very short.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="Type=text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>

</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css" /><link href="/Styles/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src='/Scripts/utilities.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>    

<script  type="text/javascript">

var f = $('iframe'),
url = f.attr('src').split('?')[0],
status = $('.status');

</script>

</head>
<body>


<center>
       <table><tr><td>
<div id="ContainPlayer" style="position:relative;"> 

          <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/79036140?autoplay=1&api=1" 
              player_id="vimeoplayer" id="vimeoplayer" 
              width="1000" height="454"
                        frameborder="0" ></iframe>

                      </div>  </td> 

              </tr></table>
</center>                   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to put your code inside the `$(document).ready()` function. You're running it before the `iframe` is loaded into the DOM. This is explained at the beginning of every jQuery tutorial.

Comment: you can't `.split()` `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function () {});`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you put the javascript before content is loaded, before the page is rendered. Move the script code after the iframe or put the block in a domready event.

```
$(function(){
var f = $('iframe'),
url = f.attr('src').split('?')[0],
status = $('.status');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either write your code...

```
 $(function() { 
here
})
```

or before the closing body tag.

The problem is that your script is executed before the html is rendered.